# For an object or class, is there a way to know all its methods?

Tags: ruby

I heard that Ruby has strong reflection and metaprogramming ability. I am wondering if there is a way to show all the methods a class or an object which I can call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost!

You can call `.methods` on any object (including a class) to get a list of which methods are available on that object.

However, `#method_missing` allows Ruby objects to respond to messages which aren't actually defined on that object. It's possible to find out for a particular method name whether an object responds to that message, but it's not possible to list all of the methods which can be caught this way.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for all the public and protected methods the instances of your class have, then you may call [`instance_methods`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods) on the class itself.

It also accepts a boolean optional argument set as true as default. True will list all the instance methods of your class superclasses, if false it will return only your class ones.

---

Answer (score 0):

An example is often helpful.  Here I've defined two classes, `A` and `B`, where `B` is a subclass of `A`. `A` has one public class method, one public instance method and one private instance method.

Class `B` has two public class methods, five public instance methods and two private instance methods.  Three of the public instance methods (`..owners`) are for displaying the owners of various methods.  In addition, `B` has all of `A`'s methods.  The focus will be on `B`.

I've begun the names of all methods with three underscores, simply to facilitate their extraction from lists of methods Ruby returns.  For example, `B` has 52 (class) methods, but the only ones whose names begin begin with three underscores are defined in `A` and `B` .

I think you can learn a lot by studying the following. Not only should it answer your question, but it will acquaint you will several Ruby methods that are quite handy, namely:

- [Object#methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-methods)
- [Module#instance_methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-instance_methods)
- [Module#private_instance_methods](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Module.html#method-i-private_instance_methods)
- [Object#method](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-method)
- [Method#owner](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Method.html#method-i-owner)

.

```
class A
  def ___aim_pub; end
  def self.___acm_pub; end
  private
  def ___aim_pvt; end
end

class B < A
  def self.___my_owners
    (my methods).each { |m| puts "#{m} owner = #{method(m).owner}" }
  end
  def ___my_owners
    (my methods).each { |m| puts "#{m} owner = #{method(m).owner}" }
  end
  def ___my_private_owners
    (my self.class.private_instance_methods).each { |m|
      puts "#{m} owner = #{method(m).owner}" }
  end

  def ___b1im_pub; end
  def ___b2im_pub; end
  def self.___b1cm_pub; end
  def self.___b2cm_pub; end

  private
  def ___b1im_pvt; end
  def ___b2im_pvt; end
end
```

*Helper*

```
def my(ms)
  ms.select { |m| m.to_s[0,3] == '___' }
end
```

*Public class methods*

```
B.methods.size
  #=> 103
my B.methods
  #=> [:___my_owners, :___b1cm_pub, :___b2cm_pub, :___acm_pub]
B.methods false
  #=> [:___my_owners, :___b1cm_pub, :___b2cm_pub]
B.___my_owners
  # ___my_owners owner = #<Class:B>
  # ___b1cm_pub owner  = #<Class:B>
  # ___b2cm_pub owner  = #<Class:B>
  # ___acm_pub owner   = #<Class:A>

b = B.new
  #=> #<B:0x000001028bbdb8>
```

*Public instance methods*

```
B.instance_methods.size
  #=> 60
B.instance_methods == b.methods
  #=> true
my B.instance_methods
  #=> [:___my_owners, :___my_private_owners, :___b1im_pub,
  #    :___b2im_pub, :___aim_pub]
B.instance_methods false
  #=> [:___my_owners, :___my_private_owners, :___b1im_pub, :___b2im_pub]
b.___my_owners
  # ___my_owners owner = B
  # ___my_private_owners owner = B
  # ___b1im_pub owner = B
  # ___b2im_pub owner = B
  # ___aim_pub owner  = A
```

*Private instance methods*

```
B.private_instance_methods.size
  #=> 78
my B.private_instance_methods
  #=> [:___b1im_pvt, :___b2im_pvt, :___aim_pvt]
B.private_instance_methods false
  #=> [:___b1im_pvt, :___b2im_pvt]
b.___my_private_owners
  # ___b1im_pvt owner = B
  # ___b2im_pvt owner = B
  # ___aim_pvt owner  = A
```